# Наследование классов С++. Ошибка на этапе работы деструктора "Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)"

Tags: c++

Добрый день.
Прошу помощи.
Сейчас изучаю наследование классов C++, и написал небольшой код по этому делу, но программа падает на этапе работы деструктора с ошибкой "Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)".
Пишу в Visual Studio 2015.
Если не передавать экземпляр класса А в экземпляр класса В, ошибки не возникает.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    char *M;
    char *Z;
public:

    A() 
    {
        M = nullptr;
        Z = nullptr;
    }

    A(char *z) 
    {
        Z = new char[strlen(z) + 1];
        strcpy_s(Z, strlen(z) + 1, z);
    }

    char* get_Z() 
    {
        return Z;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout << "Destruct" << endl;
        delete[]M;
        delete[]Z;
    }

};

class B : public A 
{
public:

    B() :A()
    {
    }

    B(A &aA) 
    {
        Z = aA.get_Z();
    }

    void show() 
    {
        cout << "Z2: " << Z << endl;
    }

};

void main() {
    A as("qwerty");
    cout << as.get_Z() << endl;

    B cv(as);
    cv.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В

```
B(A &aA) 
{
    Z = aA.get_Z();
}
```

вы присваиваете полю `Z` значение, которое оно имеет в `aA` (`as` в `main`). Затем освобождаете его как в деструкторе `as`, так и в деструкторе `cv`.

Два раза одну память освобождать нельзя...

Еще в конструкторе

```
A::A(char *z)
```

вы не присваиваете значение `M`, и оно указывает не пойми куда. В деструкторе вы освобождаете это не пойми что, что тоже делать никак нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Всё связанное с М я удалил из кода.

Как мне тогда правильно передать в класс В значение поля Z из класса А?
Ведь если не передавать экземпляр класса А в класс В, как значение по другому передать, я не знаю.

С Уважением!

Comment: Вам надо не передавать значение указателя, а выделить новую память и скопировать в нее строку.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду объявить динамический массив-буфер в глобальной области и скопировать в него строку из класса А, а потом скопировать из этого буфера в поле класса B ?

Comment: Вы уже это делали:  `Z = new char[strlen(z) + 1];
        strcpy_s(Z, strlen(z) + 1, z);` Сделать так же...

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете сделать так:

Comment: Блин, ну чуть-чуть головой можно подумать?!! `B::B(A &aA)
{
    char * z = aA.get_Z();
    if (z)
    {
        Z = new char[strlen(z) + 1];
        strcpy_s(Z, strlen(z) + 1, z);
    }
}`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
Извините за глупость...

Comment: Ну, если все понятно, и ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...